# Explain the idea of an array of contracts in solidity and the implementation of "sfStore" function in the code attached below

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, arrays, code

```
SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;

function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
    simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
}

function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
    // Address 
    // ABI 

//I could not understand the line below, do explain briefly 
simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex].store(_simpleStorageNumber);
}

function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns (uint256) {
    // return 
SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])).retrieve();
    return simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex].retrieve();
}
```

**//SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])).store(_simpleStorageNumber);

If possible breakdown the above line of code as well. This is a snippet from a tutorial where interacting with other contracts was being taught and I got completely confused when arrays came into the picture**

Comment: What is SimpleStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run the createSimpleStorageContract function, a new instance of the SimpleStorage contract is deployed. Meaning each time you click the createSimpleStorageContract button in Remix, a new instance of SimpleStorage with its own address is created on the blockchain. This function also creates an entry of the newly deployed contract's address in the simpleStorageArray starting at index 0.